# Where is Salesforce Stackexchange cloud image?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, design

[image]

I can't see the Salesforce Stackexchange cloud image. Is it a design change or it is a bug?

Comment: seems they are upgrading themes...

Comment: As well, there used to be the cloud image where it says "StackExchange"

Comment: yeah cloud image

Comment: I told everyone the cloud was an illusion that will fail one day, but did anyone listen to me? Of course not.

Comment: @Nick fail, not vanish into thin air. That's different. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that. An incorrect file path caused the image to not be shown. This has been corrected.